# Series/parallel selector switch

Tags: resistors, switches, parallel, series

Is it possible to create a circuit with three resistors that can be changed from series connection to parallel connection with a switch?

Can this be done simply enough to reproduce in a simple simulator like http://www.falstad.com/circuit/ ?

Comment: "that can be changed from series connection to parallel connection with a switch.." please give more details may be with a diagram

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without duplicating the circuit but you need two switches (DPST)

[image]

Comment: This gives a better answer to the question as asked, but given the relative cost of switches and resistors, T Borges' answer is probably a better solution to the actual problem OP needs to solve.

Comment: I was guessing the OP wanted to use the same resistors for both configurations for some reason, power resistors maybe? He seems happy with that solution though so apparently not.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as this conforms to the prerequisites in the OP's question. By the way there are situations where the cost of the switches are not as important or the cost difference does not exist. For example, power resistors are expensive, and a DPST relay is almost the same price as an SPDT one. Other is, if you have calibrated or precision resistors and you require the exact same ones to be used in both configuration.

Answer (score 1):

If you accept one dual switch, here's a 3 resistor circuit:

[image]